# How to remove metadata from the result of an elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to remove the metadata like _id, _index from the output of the elasticsearch URI query
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request for the source only by specifying the `_source` in the request like :

```
curl localhost:9200/foo/bar/1/_source
```

This will return the corresponding document only. Also you can specify the exact fields to be fetched in a query; See [docs here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html). Eg :

```
{
    "fields" : ["field_1", "field_2", "field_3"],
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "field_4" : "elastic" }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using uri query, will it work if i add other fields and other parameters too in the query?

Comment: Yes, you can specify fields in URI query, see [reference here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html)

Comment: I tried this query but it isnt working properly it is jst giving me all the source data rather than giving me just the specified fields..http://localhost:9200/test-2016.02.05/csv/id/_source?pretty&fields=alias,Name,Instance